# Creating a CFG that satisfies rules

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, language-translation, alphabet, context-free-language

So I have the following problem, I need to create a context free unambiguous grammar to meet the following criteria.

The alphabet will be { (, a, b, ), £ }, every correct string must include;

- a sequence of one or more of a/b in any order, these must be bracketed by ( )
- or a correct expression bracketed by ( and ) or a sequence of these.
- every correct string must contain a £ and this will always be the last character.

Example correct strings;

- (baabb)£
- (b)(baabb)£
- (((aba)))£
- ((bbab)((b))(ba))£

I have tried countless times to create a grammar that satisfies this and have been successful on many occasions, however the grammar has to lead to a conflict free SR parse table and in every case I have tried I am unable to make it conflict free. If anyone has any tips on how to convert a language I already have to a conflict free one please comment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Funny how `£` looks like a Britishized `$`, or `#`. Weren't the days of code pages long past? (just joking)

Comment: You seem to be mostly on the right track with your last attempt. But anyway I added a working grammar as a new answer, which I tested with your test cases (and a couple of strings which I thought should be rejected, `ab£` and `((ab)ab)£`) and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this problem (and the way I should have started with) is to just reproduce the rules as a context-free grammar.

1. A correct expression (`E`) is a sequence of one or more of `a`/`b` (`A`) in any order (`C`) bracketed by `(` `)`.

   ```
    A → a
    A → b
    C → A
    C → C A
    E → ( C )
   ```
2. Or a correct expression bracketed by `(` `)` or a sequence (`S`) of those

   ```
    E → ( S )
    S → S E
    S → E
   ```
3. Every correct string must contain a £ and this will always be the last character.

   ```
    T → S £
   ```

The only part of this which might need an explanation is the second point. The usual way of writing a Dyck grammar (that is, a parenthesized expression) is with the help of the rules `S → ( S ) S; S → λ` (where λ indicates an empty right-hand side). But in this problem, there must be something between the parentheses and there is apparently a requirement that the grammar not include λ-rules. To accommodate these requirements, I split the rule into two: `E` is a single parenthesized expression, and `S` is a non-empty sequence.

Comment: So, Using this I have just tested this with the following (a)(ab)$ but it does not work. i.e. there is no derivation for this using the grammar described above. I can only achieve this by using the following rules; Start symbol: S
S → (L)S | $
L → (L)L | (L) | E | A
E → LA
A → a | b, but as I mentioned I get SR conflicts when using this grammar :(

Comment: @KyleB9; maybe i read requirement 2 incorrectly. Just change my top-level rule to ` T → S £`

Comment: @KyleB9: I don't know. Why does it matter?